# Colon in a Fortran output statement with an implied DO

Tags: fortran

We are having to convert some old Fortran 77 code to VB.net.  With none of us knowing any Fortran, we have made significant progress.
However, we have come across the following write statement which has a couple of nested implied do loops.  We are familiar with implied do loops but do not know what the significance of the colon in `MN:MN` is.  We've only ever seen implied do loops using commas such as the latter one in this statement `(NREC,MN)`.

```
Logical*1 DECLN(492)

WRITE(6,9238)NPERMN(NREC),CUSIPS(NREC),TICKRS(NREC),NAMES(NREC),(DECLN(MN:MN),MN=1,30),(SCORES(NREC,MN),MN=1,30))

format(I7, 1X, A8, 1X, A8, 1X, A20, 1X, 12A1, 1X, 12A1, 1X, 6A1/(12F10.5))
```

Comment: This code is weird - variables list _inside_ the `WRITE` statement. `WRITE(6,*) NPERMN(NREC),...` or `WRITE(6,fmt_or_line_number) NPERMN(NREC),...` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Because this code will be incorporated into some existing .net processes.

Comment: @Hristo.  You are correct. I have fixed the line.  Must have missed something during the copy/paste.

Comment: Could you please also show us the line that starts with `9238` so we can see the `FORMAT` specifier? It might give us a clue why an implied loop is used instead of just `DECLN(1:30)`.

Comment: Here's a little more information:

Comment: DECLN is an array of Logical*1 values.  I'm not sure yet if those are Byte values (-128 to 127) or true/false.
DECLN(MN:MN), MN=1,30 is grabbing the first 30 of those values and writing them out (along with the other values) in the format referenced at label 9238:
format(I7, 1X, A8, 1X, A8, 1X, A20, 1X, 12A1, 1X, 12A1, 1X, 6A1/(12F10.5))
So 12A1, 1X, 12A1, 1x, 6A1 handle the 30 values.  Which seem to indicate 1 character values (A1)?  Yet there is a previous line that shows If DECLN(mn).lt.11.  So that can't be??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLN(MN:MN)
```

looks like a 1-character extract from a character variable called `DECLN`.  The expression

```
(DECLN(MN:MN),MN=1,30)
```

(which is an `io-implied-do` expression) causes the program to write the first 30 characters of `DECLN` as 30 separate characters.  The form

```
(DECLN(1:30))
```

writes the same characters in one 30-character long go.

It might be that `DECLN(MN:MN)` is a 1-element section of the rank-1 array `DECLN`, in which case it's an odd way to write `DECLN(MN)`

Comment: Didn't know that Fortran 77 supports array sections for anything different than character arrays...

Comment: I originally thought it might be a one character extract but then yeah, why not just (DECLN(1:30))?

Comment: I'm not sure FORTRAN77 does support general array sections, but FORTRAN77 programs are rarely pure FORTRAN77, usually they're written in FORTRAN77+extensions and I'm not going to trawl through my memory banks to try and recall all the extensions to FORTRAN77 that I've ever seen :-)

Comment: Happily your question was about what the statement means, not about why the *expletive deleted* statement was written that way.

Comment: Very true, hpm.  I"m going to mark this as correct since it does indeed appear to simply be a substring extract of 1 character at element 30.

Comment: Actually it appears to be pulling out 30 characters starting at index 1!

Comment: @HristoIliev -- Array sections for anything other than *character strings* are an extension to fortran 77 (I believe it is possible to declare a character array that is not a string).

Comment: @mgilson, right - strings like `CHARACTER BLAH*N` and not `CHARACTER BLAH(N)`.

Comment: @HristoIliev : I've often wondered why people didn't use the second form more often when mixing fortran/c code in the days before `iso_bind_c` ...

Comment: If the code is really F77 (so DECLN must be character), then the implied do shown in this response supplies thirty items.  DECLN(1:30) supplies a single item.  That difference is significant when considering the interaction between the item list and the format specification - consider a format specification of ``(30(A,' '))`` versus ``(A)``.

Comment: @IanH, that's exactly the reason why I asked the OP to provide the line with the format statement.

Answer (score 2):

DECLN(MN:MN) is used to extract a single character from a string.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the update, DECLN is not character; it is 1-byte LOGICAL array (containing info about securities). (DECLN(MN:MN),MN=1,30) is identifying the first 30 elements, but I think could more easily be written (DECLN(MN),MN=1,30). The CUSIPs (which are 9-digit codes) are being written A8, which truncates the checksum (typical enough procedure, which I'm sure Brian knows because most clearing bodies ignore it)